# Форматирование строки с десятичной дробью

Tags: python, python-2.7, форматирование

У меня есть строка вида

```
"{0:.2f}sec/{1}".format(my_variable, other_variable)
```

`my_variable` это `float`. Я хочу чтобы она занимала 5 символов.
Для обычной переменной я сделал бы так:

```
"{0: <5}".format(my_variable)
```

Я пробовал:

```
"{0:.2f <5} }sec/{1}".format(my_variable, other_variable)
"{0:.2f: <5} }sec/{1}".format(my_variable, other_variable)
```

но вылетает

```
ValueError: Invalid conversion specification
```

Как сделать так, чтобы `my_variable` занимала 5 символов?
Примеры вывода:

```
"23.45"
" 2.34"
" 0.30"
```

Comment: "Всего" 5 символов? Включая точку и целую часть? Вроде 0.000 42.00 155.0?

Comment: да, включая точку и целую часть.
Пример вывода, который я пытаюсь получить:
`12.22`, ` 0.23`, `1.70`, то есть недостающие числа заменяются пробелами.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Формат: `{:5.2f}`

```
>>> '{:5.2f}'.format(3.3)
' 3.30'
```